# Проблема с отправкой сообщения на почту с помощью smtplib. Ошибка login raise last_exception

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

Всем привет, хотел создать программу которая смотрит какая система у человека и отправляет отчёт мне на почту, но выходит ошибка

Вот код:

'''

```
import platform

import smtplib

def send_mail(email, password, message):

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) 

    server.starttls() 

    server.login(email, password)

    server.sendmail(email, email, message) 

    server.quit() 

result = platform.platform()

send_mail("testerson202122@gmail.com", "xrengoogle", result) 

print("Твой мессидж отправлен")
```

'''

Comment: вот ошибка:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bbbbb.py", line 12, in <module>
    send_mail("testerson202122@gmail.com", "xrengoogle", result)
  File "bbbbb.py", line 6, in send_mail
    server.login(email, password) # авторизация. 1ый параметр - ваш адрес, 2ой - пароль от вашего адреса электронной почты, с это почты и будет отправлено письмо
  File "C:\Users\BaDRa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File

Comment: "C:\Users\BaDRa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\BaDRa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv\n5.7.14 1DmC6WCvD-YZPucP33TcZgyQhaoYrFObd99uo8SjP8EHk05_wcP2recaZD

Comment: aNgQv5kGmC6\n5.7.14 x_EWBeNgplU9Q4ISq0NtPxdLlMmsrWsWisWXtIu0rUlj08zAjKry1LLWZbr9v2ya>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 v20sm362111lji.64 - gsmtp')

Comment: Всю информацию в вопрос с помощью кнопки править (отредактируйте ошибки и код нормально), а комментарии удалите

Comment: @BaDRabbiT404 А вы пройдите по ссылке то, которая https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 там много интересного написано. Возможно, надо что-то разрешить, прежде чем

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: А нет, все указания были выполнены, но ошибка на своём месте( Памагити!